# Retrieve available clients via UDP broadcast

Tags: networking, tcp, server, udp

I'm currently developing a "node-based" system where a server will send out a UDP broadcast on the private network (with a custom protocol), which will be received by several different clients which supports the specified protocol. The server will after the request pick between some of the clients for a more steady TCP connection.

### Request for client sequence

1. Server broadcasting a ***request-for-ip*** message to every device/node on the network.
2. All available clients that supports the protocol will answer with their unique IP to the server.
3. Server chooses among the clients via a ***request-for-connection*** message.
4. Client that got choosen by the server connects to the server via TCP for a reliable connection.

### My question

I've got pretty good knowledge about both TCP and UDP, but I've never designed a system like this before.  Do you think this system is built in the right way or is there a more "standard" way doing something similar to this? What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

## --- Edit ---

Added a diagram of the program.

## [image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense. It is the clients that should discover the server, not the other way round. After all it is the clients that initiate the connections. Having the server discover the clients isn't any use at all.

Comment: Broadcast for such things is really no longer used because it interrupts _every_ host on the network, including things like routers, server, printers, etc. that are not interested in the packets. The modern way to do this is to use multicast. Have the device being searched for subscribe to a multicast group, then have the searching devices send a message to the multicast group. This only interrupts the interested hosts.

Comment: My idea was that a "master" client would connect to the server and then use other "slave" clients for different purposes. The server will basically broadcast and lookup all of the available "slave" clients and then display it to the "master" client. I will look more into multicast and check if that's what I need! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard protocol to advertise services on the network, which you may like to consider: [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol), based on periodic UDP multicast:

> The Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP) is a network protocol based on the Internet protocol suite for advertisement and discovery of network services and presence information. It accomplishes this without assistance of server-based configuration mechanisms, such as Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) or Domain Name System (DNS), and without special static configuration of a network host. SSDP is the basis of the discovery protocol of Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) and is intended for use in residential or small office environments.

In this protocol clients join that UDP multicast group to discover local network services and initiate connections to them, if they wish to. And this is pretty much the intended use case for the protocol, which is somewhat different from your use case.

One benefit of IP/UDP multicast is that multicast packets can be dropped in the network adapter if no process on the host has joined that multicast group. Another one is that IP/UDP multicast can be routed across networks.

---

From the diagram you posted:

- The server is the mediator (design pattern) whose location must be known to every other process of the distributed system.
- The clients need to connect/register with the server.
- Your master client is a control application.

It makes sense for the server to advertise itself over UDP multi-cast.

Online clients would connect to the server using TCP on start or TCP connection loss. If a client terminates for any reason that breaks the TCP connection and the server becomes immediately aware of that, unless the client was powered off or its OS crashed. You may like to enable frequent TCP keep-alives for the server to detect dead clients as soon as possible, if no data is being transmitted from the server to the clients. Same applies to the clients.

All communications between the server and the clients happen over TCP. Otherwise you would need to implement reliable messaging over UDP or use [PGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_General_Multicast), which can be a lot of work. Multicast UDP should only be used for server discovery, not bi-directional communication that requires reliable delivery.

The master client also connects to the server, possibly on another port, for control. The master client can discover all available servers (if there is more than one) and allow the user to choose which one to connect to.

Comment: I've not built the discovery system yet, because I'm still figuring out how I should do this in the best way possible. What I need is a way to make a "master client" choose between different "slave clients" that are running on the network. My first thought was that the server discovers "slave clients" automatically via broadcast/multicast on the network, which then can be accessed and choosen between via the the "master client". What do you think, is this good or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Warcaith Given multiple hosts, how do you choose the master one, what is the criteria?

Comment: That's a very good question. The "master client" will make use of different "slave clients" to load software to different kind of embedded devices. The "slave clients" can be different instruments, for example a power supply unit but also a non-physical client that has the purpose to retrieve the right software and send it over to the device via UDP. The "master" client will be sort of the program that makes every part of the system work together.

Comment: The reason I wanna use multicast and discovery is that the program will need to be able to load many DIFFERENT devices at the same time. The clients are built in a kind of "generic" way, which means that they will be reuseable for different products.

Comment: It is not an easy task to describe this system in a good way, haha. But in short, when an operator is starting the software load, the "master client" will check via the server's broadcast functionality if all the necessary "slave client" are running.

Comment: I had an idea that the "master client" would "lease" the clients for a short amount of time and then let them go after the software load has been completed.

Comment: Sequence:
"Master client" checks with the server if all of the "slave clients" are available via a broadcast/multicast message -> "Slave clients" responds to the server -> "Master" leases and makes specific "slaves" connect to the server via TCP, which when leased turns of their UDP discover functionality until released -> "Master" starts the software load -> Software load done -> Server releases "slaves" -> All "slaves" that was leased starts over and begins listen for new "masters"

Comment: I will update the original post with a diagram in a short amount amount of time!

Comment: @Warcaith Since your master is a special application, may the master application should advertise itself over UDP multicast and all slaves connect to it using TCP?

Comment: Well, that's maybe what I'm trying to do. The "master" application will always be the one that starts the server. Your idea is that I should combine the "master client" and the "server" into one application?

Comment: @Warcaith Since master is _the program that makes every part of the system work together_ it would be simplest it it was a dedicated application that advertises itself to the clients. No need to choose a master algorithmically.

Comment: I've uploaded an image in the original post now that shows how I planned to create this application in the beginning. If I understand you correctly, you would integrate the server and the discovery functionalities directly into the "master" instead of seperating them into two applications?

Comment: @Warcaith Updated the answer for you. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, thank you! I've got some question though. The server will, as we agreed on, send a multicast to retrieve a list of online **slave client**, but should they really connect via TCP on start? What if the **master client** only needs 2 out of 4 power supply unit **slave clients**? Should the _"lease a client"_ approach work maybe?

Comment: **Server** sends unicast: _[server - ip:port] request-lease_ -> **Slave client** answers by connecting via TCP

Comment: @Warcaith The idea is that the server only learns about clients once they connect to the server over TCP. The clients can send their properties/features to the server upon connect, or upon server request over that TCP connection. Having those properties the server can decide how to manage those clients. The server sends commands to clients only over those TCP connection. Otherwise you'd have to implement reliable messaging over UDP on your own.

Comment: That will work perfectly, except for one small detail.. you will bind all available clients to the server even if you don't need all of them. What if another master needs to use some of the running **slave clients**? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Warcaith Well then, all clients TCP connect to all available masters. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Well, that's entirely true, you nailed it. I think one problem can occur by this approach though and that's conflicts when two different **masters** are controlling the same **slave**, but I could just lock the **slave client** from being manipulated by any other **master client** than the one that currently controls it, which makes the problem disappear. I'll try to implement a prototype of this tomorrow and then report back with how it goes. Thanks for the help Maxim!